# I have an object selection problem

Tags: edit-mode, object-mode

recently I have this problem, I was modeling a character and out of nowhere I no longer had the possibility to select it, the strange thing is that when I go to the layer of the object and enter to edit mode it works, but if I select it in object mode it stops working again.
when I create any other object it also selects it normally, it is as if something had been blocked in the collection.
maybe I have blocked something by accident?
[image]

[image]

Comment: maybe you have disabled its selectability in the Outliner? please share your file: https://pasteall.org/blend/

Comment: https://pasteall.org/blend/f23001291c1d404682f154d8e545766a

Comment: clever! thank you very much for your help and sorry for the delay

Answer (score 3):

Display the selectability option of the objects in the *Outliner*:

[image]

You'll see that it is disabled for the tail object:

[image]

Comment: thank you so much! it works good now